# I would like to get ratings and destructure it when I console the props.ratings I get Array(1) but I get (found: object with keys {star, ,...}

Tags: reactjs, jsx

> ERROR Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {star, review, reviewDate, name, userID}). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead.

and my console.log(props.ratings) I get [{…}]  0

```
<>
  {props?.ratings.map((item, index) => {
    const { star, review, reviewDate, name, userID } = item;
    return (
      <div key={index} className="review">
        <StarRating
          starDimension="20px"
          starSpacing="2px"
          starRatedColor="#F6B01E"
          rating={star}
          editing={false}
        />
        <p>{review}</p>
        <span>
          <b>{reviewDate}</b>
        </span>
        <br />
        <span>
          <b>by: {name}</b>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</>
```

> ERROR Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {star, review, reviewDate, name, userID}). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead.

And my console.log(props.ratings) I get `[{…}]  0 :  {star: 2, review: 'not satisfied', reviewDate: 'Tue Feb 27 2024', name: 'Feisal', userID: '65d5d891dc5ae55627c99ebd'} length :  1 [[Prototype]] :  Array(0)`.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to render some `item` object directly somewhere in your code. Are you sure *this* is the problematic code? *What* console log are you referring to? There's none in your example code. See [mcve].

Comment: it seems the problem is review props, the problem can be for several reasons: passing an Object/ Non-Serializable Data/ Array as a child, 
What is the value of the review?

Answer (score 0):

possibly your error is not coming from your provided piece of code

```
<>
    {props?.ratings.map((item, index) => {
        const { star, review, reviewDate, name, userID } = item;
        return (
            <div key={index} className='review'>
                <StarRating
                    starDimension='20px'
                    starSpacing='2px'
                    starRatedColor='#F6B01E'
                    rating={star}
                    editing={false}
                />
                <p>{review}</p>
                <span>
                    <b>{reviewDate}</b>
                </span>
                <br />
                <span>
                    <b>by: {name}</b>
                </span>
            </div>
        );
    })}
</>
```

However, the error you're encountering usually occurs when props.ratings is not an array during some render cycles. To avoid this, you can add a conditional check before calling map to ensure that props.ratings is indeed an array.

```
<>
    {Array.isArray(props?.ratings) &&
        props?.ratings.map((item, index) => {
            const { star, review, reviewDate, name, userID } = item;
            return (
                <div key={index} className='review'>
                    <StarRating
                        starDimension='20px'
                        starSpacing='2px'
                        starRatedColor='#F6B01E'
                        rating={star}
                        editing={false}
                    />
                    <p>{review}</p>
                    <span>
                        <b>{reviewDate}</b>
                    </span>
                    <br />
                    <span>
                        <b>by: {name}</b>
                    </span>
                </div>
            );
        })
    }
</>
```

this error actually comes when you try to render `item` directly in you jsx code like below

```
<>
    {props?.ratings.map((item, index) => {
        
        return (
            <div key={index} className='review'>
                {item}
            </div>
        );
    })}
</>
```